# VB toggle specific form with key press events

Tags: .net, vb.net, keypress, keydown

Hello I'm having difficulty showing a form when a specific set of keys are pressed. The main form runs first; this is a second form that’s supposed to be hidden until toggled by pressing ctrl+alt+shift+h. This is the code that I have, I believe it should work, but it is not. I tried it like this, in a timer that checks for the press events every 1 millisec

```
Private Sub tmrKeys_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrKeys.Tick
    Dim key As String = Nothing

    If My.Computer.Keyboard.AltKeyDown AndAlso My.Computer.Keyboard.CtrlKeyDown AndAlso My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown AndAlso key = "H" Then
        Dim x = New form2()
        x.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```

And I also tried a separate function like this:

```
Private Sub form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.Control AndAlso e.Alt AndAlso e.Shift AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.H Then
        form2.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: You absolutely should not be using a `Timer`. Not under any circumstances. The first question is whether you want this key combination to work only while your main form has focus or regardless of what window has focus. If it's the latter then you need to use the Windows API to register a hotkey. For the former, your second code snippet is correct but the form will not raise that `KeyDown` event by default if it has selectable controls on it. To get such a form to raise keybaod events, you must set its `KeyPreview` property to `True`.

Comment: It needs to be toggled when the keys are pressed regardless of the focus of the form.

Comment: In that case, handling events of the form is useless because those events can't be raised if the form doesn't have focus.  You should look into the `RegisterHotKey` API.  You'll be able to find plenty of examples with a search. Just make sure that you either use specifically VB.NET examples or make the appropriate changes to VB6 examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was looking for. Thank you to @jmcilhinney for the hint towards RegisterHotKey on how to register active hotkeys. This code sets the hotkeys to alt+UPKEY. I want to figure out how to modify the parameters to assign more than 2 keys, like CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+UPKEY. But I have to head to work, so I’ll work on it tonight and update it tomorrow for everyone, unless an eager beaver wants to show me how to do this while I’m at work lol. Thanks again to everyone that helped!

```
Public Class Form1

Public Declare Function RegisterHotKey Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal id As Integer, ByVal fsModifiers As Integer, ByVal vk As Integer) As Integer
Public Declare Function UnregisterHotKey Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal id As Integer) As Integer
Public Const WM_HOTKEY As Integer = &H312


Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    If m.Msg = WM_HOTKEY Then
        Form2.Show()
    End If

    MyBase.WndProc(m)

End Sub


Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Call UnregisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 9)

End Sub


Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Call RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle.ToInt32, 0, &H1, 38) '<-- registers specific hotkeys

End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code looks ok (no need for a timer). I think what you are missing is the setting of the [`KeyPreview`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview(v=vs.110).aspx) to `True`

> When this property is set to true, the form will receive all
>   KeyPress, KeyDown, and KeyUp events

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Form1.KeyPreview = True
End Sub
```

Then this should work:

```
Private Sub form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.Control AndAlso e.Alt AndAlso e.Shift AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.H Then
        form2.Show()
    End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: That quote is drastically inaccurate, no KeyPress or KeyUp and not all keys.  Where did you copy it from?

Comment: @HansPassant - it is on the MSDN page I linked to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @BanForFun - it didn't work for me without setting this property (VS2015)

Comment: Neither of the methods shown work. still nothing is toggled.